# Android AsyncTask Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

i have some problem when i parse the JSON in asyncTask Android Studio
its showed: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

this my code:

```
@Override
protected Response doInBackground(String... objects) {
    try {
        String stringResponse = loadJSON(objects[0]);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(stringResponse, Response.class);


    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

and this is my JSON

```
   [{"Code":"ascascasd",
    "SKU":"asd",
    "Name":"asd",
    "Description":"d",
    ...
    ...
   }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stringResponse should contain

```
{"Code":"ascascasd",
    "SKU":"asd",
    "Name":"asd",
    "Description":"d",
    ...
    ...
   }
```

and not

```
[{"Code":"ascascasd",
    "SKU":"asd",
    "Name":"asd",
    "Description":"d",
    ...
    ...
   }]
```

Or add another class that contains list of "Response" objects and pass the new class to gson.fromJson()